# Need Toggle button in menu in both desktop and mobile version in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

On opening web page in mobile version, menu comes in toggle button, but when open in desktop, it display the menu without toggle.

How to display menu in toggle button for desktop version also in bootstrap?

Comment: its Code on `media query`

Comment: where exactly do i need to make changes for that?

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using. please add your code.

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.hamberger').click(function() {
  $('.hamberger-navbar').toggleClass('active-left');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  }
header,
nav {
  display: block;
}
.container-fluid {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #795548;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
#navbar {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
}
#navbar li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 19.5px;
}
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e0dbd1;
  font-family: verdana;
}
#navbar li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #795548;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: verdana;
}
.hamberger {
  display: none;
}
.hamberger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

.hamberger span,
.hamberger span:before,
.hamberger span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-color:#ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamberger span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

.hamberger span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

.hamberger span,
.hamberger span:before,
.hamberger span:after {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.hamberger.active span {
  background-color: transparent
}

.hamberger.active span:before,
.hamberger.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

.hamberger.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamberger.active span:after {
  top: 10px;
  transform: translatey(-10px)   rotate(-45deg);
}

@media (max-width: 1024px){
    .hamberger-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    left: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  .hamberger-navbar.active-left {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .hamberger-navbar.active-left:after {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  #navbar {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
    #navbar ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  #navbar li {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #navbar li a {
    float: none;
  }
  .hamberger {
    float: left;
    margin: 17px 0 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    display: block;
  }
}
 @media (max-width: 991px){
  .hamberger-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    left: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  .hamberger-navbar.active-left {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .hamberger-navbar.active-left:after {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: -1;
  }

  #navbar {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  #navbar ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  #navbar li {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #navbar li a {
    float: none;
  }
  .hamberger {
    float: left;
    margin: 17px 0 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    display: block;
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="hamberger">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    <nav id="navbar" class="hamberger-navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="navigation">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="navigation">Products</a></li>
            <li><a class="navigation">Header Style</a></li>
            <li><a class="navigation">Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a class="navigation">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

See this one i think its usefull to you.